# bashで正規表現の後方参照

Tags: bash, centos, 正規表現

CentOSを使っているのですが、bashのコマンドラインで `aaa1.txt` から `aaa5.txt` まで連続した番号のものを圧縮したい場合には、

```
$ gzip aaa[1-5].txt
```

とすればできますが、たぶんこれは `gzip` が正規表現に対応しているからだろうと思います。

また、よく `ls` や `grep` などでアスタリスクを使ったりするのですが、これもそうだろうと思います。`sed` では後方参照ができますが、一方で

```
$ mv aaa￥([1-5]￥).txt bbb￥1.txt
```

なんてやってもうまくいきません。

シェルスクリプトを書くまでもない処理で、こういう後方参照をする方法というのはあるのでしょうか？

Comment: パス名展開は`gzip`ではなくてシェルの機能です。また、置換文字列内でキャプチャグループを参照するのは「後方参照」ではありません。

Comment: 正規表現でマッチしたものを、再利用するのが後方参照だと思っていました。シェルの機能はパス名展開なのですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一般解はさておき、例に挙げられたファイル名変更については、CentOSの最小構成でもrenameコマンドが使えるかと思います。

```
$ rename aaa bbb aaa[1-5].txt
```

なお、renameコマンドは、Red Hat系（CentOSなどを含む）とDebian系（Ubuntuなどを含む）とで、使い方の異なるまったく別のコマンドが入っているのはご注意。

Comment: これが一番シンプルですね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4):

Unix/Linux (というか bash) ではコマンドラインの展開を行うのは bash の仕事ということになっています。

$ gzip aaa[1-5].txt
と入力したらこのファイル名展開を行うのは bash であり、起動されるコマンドは
$ gzip aaa1.txt aaa2.txt aaa3.txt aaa4.txt aaa5.txt
となります。 gzip が展開を行っているわけではありません。

一方で mv の仕様として
mv file1 file2 (file1 を file2 に改名する：このときは引数は２個でなければならない)
mv file1 directory (file1 を directory/file1 に改名する)
mv file1 file2 ... directory (引数が３つ以上のとき、最後の引数はディレクトリを指定する必要がある)
なので、提示の mv は動かないのが当然ということになります。

提示 mv で何がしたいのか微妙につかめませんが
aaa/aaa*.txt を bbb ディレクトリに移す (aaa*.txt のまま) のなら
`mv aaa/aaa*.txt bbb` でしょうし

bbb*.txt に名前を変更しながら bbb ディレクトリに移すのなら

```
for i in aaa/aaa*.txt; do mv $i `sed s/aaa/bbb/g`; done
```

となるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やりたかったのは、
aaa1.txtをbbb1.txtに、
aaa2.txtをbbb2.txtに…
ということをやりたかったのですが、
実はファイル名展開をしているのであれば、難しそうですね。

Comment: ファイル名の改名をしたいのであれば mv をファイルの個数だけ起動する必要があります。
for  mv sed でできますよ (コメント欄で書くのは困難なので省略)
既に提示してある例をちょっと変更するだけです。

Comment: ちなみに，こういったシンプルな変更であれば `sed` もいいですが変数内での文字列置換を使うのも手だと思います（ `a=foobar; echo ${a/oo/00}`）．